# Android: ExpandableListActivity And Support Library

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-support-library

I have an activity that uses `ExpandableListActivity` but now I want it to use `LoaderManager`. Unluckily to use it on older devices I need to use support library and... I need to extend `ActivityCompat` or any other child-class. There is no `ExpandableListActivity` in support library as far, as I can see.

What are my options in this case? Any other way to get LoaderManager from the support library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FragmentActivity & loaders, but inflate ExpandableListView directly, and bind data to it via ExpandableListAdapter

Comment: This is why you never use ExpandableListActivity :p